# XML serialization override dervied class name with XSI:Type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am using following code for Student and Employee class derived from Person.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Student)), XmlInclude(typeof(Employee))]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Student")]
public class Student : Person
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Subjects { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Employee")]
public class Employee : Person
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public float Experience { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating a list of Person classes and initiate with following values and generating XML by serializing the same.

```
public class TestSerialization
{        
    List<Person> lstPerson = new List<Person>();

    public void XMLGen()
    {  

        Person obj = new Person() { Name = "Person1", Age = 10, Gender = "M" };
        Person obj2 = new Person() { Name = "Person2", Age = 10, Gender = "F" };

        Student objS = new Student()
        {
            Name = "Student1",
            Age = 20,
            Gender = "M",
            StudentId = 1,
            Subjects = new List<string>() { "Math", "Science" }
        };
        Student objS2 = new Student()
        {
            Name = "Student2",
            Age = 15,
            Gender = "F",
            StudentId = 1,
            Subjects = new List<string>() { "Physics", "Chemistry" }
        };

        Employee objE = new Employee()
        {
            Name = "Employee1",
            Age = 15,
            Gender = "F",
            EmployeeId = 1,
            Experience = 5.5f
        };

        Employee objE2 = new Employee()
        {
            Name = "Employee2",
            Age = 15,
            Gender = "M",
            EmployeeId = 2,
            Experience = 6.5f
        };

        lstPerson.Add(obj);
        lstPerson.Add(obj2);
        lstPerson.Add(objS);
        lstPerson.Add(objS2);
        lstPerson.Add(objE);
        lstPerson.Add(objE2);

        Type[] types = { typeof(Student), typeof(Employee) };

        XmlSerializer objXml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>), types);

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            objXml.Serialize(textWriter, lstPerson);
            string aa = textWriter.ToString();
        }

    }

}
```

But XML that generated contains derived class name as xsi:type="Student" and xsi:type="Employee" as shown below.

```
<Person xsi:type="Student">
<Name>Student1</Name>
<Age>20</Age>
<Gender>M</Gender>
<StudentId>1</StudentId>
<Subjects>
  <string>Math</string>
  <string>Science</string>
</Subjects>
```

and for Employee it is

```
<Person xsi:type="Employee">
<Name>Employee2</Name>
<Age>15</Age>
<Gender>M</Gender>
<EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
<Experience>6.5</Experience>
```

Is it possible the we get XML node name as Student,Employee rather than Person with xsi:type?

I want XML should be like this.

```
<Employee>
<Name>Employee2</Name>
<Age>15</Age>
<Gender>M</Gender>
<EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
<Experience>6.5</Experience>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xsi:type` is needed for deserialization, when you try to read from the XML again. Otherwise the deserializer wouldn't know what class to deserialize to.

If you are not planning to deserialize into a class again, then you could add your own custom serializer.

Comment: Still getting same results <Person xsi:type="Employee">

Comment: I thought I had done this before, but it was a different scenario. My answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding xmlroot should give the root tag as employee.  You cannot eliminate the type attribute because of the inheritance in the class structure.

```
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Student)), XmlInclude(typeof(Employee))]
    [XmlRoot("Employee")]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("Student")]
    public class Student : Person
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public List<string> Subjects { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("Employee")]
    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public float Experience { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z3z5s6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx link. Use XmlElementAttribute to change element name and add the XmlElementAttribute to a XmlAttributes instance. Then add the XmlAttributes to a XmlAttributeOverrides instance, specifying the type being overridden and the name of the member that accepts the derived class.

```
public class Orders
{
    public List<Person> Persons;
}

 public void SerializeObject(string filename)
    {
        // Each overridden field, property, or type requires 
        // an XmlAttributes instance.
        XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

        // Creates an XmlElementAttribute instance to override the 
        // field that returns Book objects. The overridden field
        // returns Expanded objects instead.
        XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute();
        attr.ElementName = "Student";
        attr.Type = typeof(Student);

        XmlElementAttribute attrE = new XmlElementAttribute();
        attrE.ElementName = "Employee";
        attrE.Type = typeof(Employee);

        // Adds the element to the collection of elements.
        attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);
        attrs.XmlElements.Add(attrE);

        // Creates the XmlAttributeOverrides instance.
        XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        // Adds the type of the class that contains the overridden 
        // member, as well as the XmlAttributes instance to override it 
        // with, to the XmlAttributeOverrides.
        attrOverrides.Add(typeof(Orders), "Persons", attrs);

        // Creates the XmlSerializer using the XmlAttributeOverrides.
        XmlSerializer s =
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orders), attrOverrides);
```

During serialization, it will use override attributes to overrride their properties.